# How can i find that which file was copied from my pendrive last time?

Tags: 12.04, security, usb-drive

I forget my pendrive in my office. I have doubt that someone copies my important documents and files from my pendrive.

Is there any method to find that which file is copied from my pen-drive?

Please tell me also if finding the mac address is possible from which my pen drive is accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no; last access time is the only thing that can help you and it's not recorded by default on FAT filesystems (if you try with `stat`, you'll find a semi-fake number, based on last mount I think):

```
θ64° [romano:/media/romano/PEN8G] % stat present.pdf
  File: ‘present.pdf’
  Size: 291235      Blocks: 576        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 821h/2081d  Inode: 1599        Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1153/  romano)   Gid: ( 1001/  romano)
Access: 2016-04-22 00:00:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2016-03-08 10:31:56.000000000 +0100
Change: 2016-03-10 11:05:26.000000000 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Seems that access has a 1-day granularity.

And no, there is no log of which device accessed your pen drive.

Anyhow, anyone that has copied your files can also have faked the last access time or whatever, so no, there is no way to safely say if the files have been read, copied or whatever.

Encryption is the only safe way to store things on pen drives.